# Question about adding a layer after loading pre-trained weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a question about creating a deep neural network with partially loading weights.

Suppose I construct a model as follows (assume a sequence of layers are specified for the model):

```
model = models.Model(inputs, x, name=model_name)
```

And then, I load the weights for the model.

```
model.load_weights(weights)
```

What I want to do next is add additional layers to the deep network model that I have just created, initializing the corresponding weights to random values.

I am not sure what is a proper way to do this, so could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a model loaded with pretrained weights

```
model.load_weights(weights)
#Set trainable to false to maintain the previous weights
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Down below you will see some examples, but make sure you consult the https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers for all types of initializers.

#### Sequential model way

```
initializer_1 = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()
dense_1 = model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu',kernel_initializer = initializer_1))
initializer_2 = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()
model.add(Dense(256,activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer = initializer_2))
```

#### Functional model way

```
initializer_1 = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()
dense_1 = Dense(512,activation='relu',kernel_initializer = initializer_1)(model.output)
initializer_2 = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()
dense_2 = Dense(256,activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer = initializer_2)(dense_1)
```

By default, the newly added are trainable, so you do not need to worry about setting the `trainable` property.